# Sort table by name and display the name on top of the table

Tags: java, sql, itext

I'm using itextpdf to display the result from my SQL query (it's not the actual query, I just made it simpler):

```
SELECT ID, NAME, AGE from CUSTOMERS ORDER BY NAME;
```

And I've been trying to separate the result according to a column called "Name" and display it on top of the table like this:

```
Mark
ID      |    Age
1111          21
2222          22
3333          23

John
ID      |  Age
4444        24
5555        25
6666        26
```

The only solution I could of is to hard code it, maybe something like this:

```
// Display Name on top of the table
while(rs.next()){
    String name = rs.getString(2);

    if(name.equals("Mark")){
        Paragraph name_Prgph = new Paragraph("Mark", header_Bold);
        name_Prgph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        name_Prgph.setSpacingAfter(10);
        my_pdf_report.add(name_Prgph);
        break;
    }
}

// Table Header
rowHeader_Table.addCell(new Phrase("ID", header_Bold));
rowHeader_Table.addCell(new Phrase("NAME", header_Bold));
rowHeader_Table.addCell(new Phrase("AGE", header_Bold));

//Table Values
while(result.next()){
    String id_Values = result.getInt(1);
    String name_Values = result.getString(2);
    Integer age_Values = result.getInt(3);

    if(name_Values.equals("Mark")){
                                    
        a.addCell(new Phrase(Integer.toString(id_Values), normalFont));
        a.addCell(new Phrase(Integer.toString(age_Values), normalFont));
    }
}
```

EDIT: I just learned that you can't use resultset.next() twice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use java collections something like this:-

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

// Display Name on top of the table
while(rs.next()){
    String name = rs.getString(2);

    if (!names.contains(name)){
        names.add(name);
        Paragraph name_Prgph = new Paragraph(name, header_Bold);
        name_Prgph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        name_Prgph.setSpacingAfter(10);
        my_pdf_report.add(name_Prgph);
       // Table Header
       rowHeader_Table.addCell(new Phrase("ID", header_Bold));
       rowHeader_Table.addCell(new Phrase("AGE", header_Bold));
    }
    //Add values
    String id_Values = result.getInt(1);
    Integer age_Values = result.getInt(3);
                                    
    a.addCell(new Phrase(Integer.toString(id_Values), normalFont));
    a.addCell(new Phrase(Integer.toString(age_Values), normalFont));

}
```

#Untested

Comment: All the names are displayed before the row header and the values but thanks to you, I've come up with a solution. Instead of using `Paragraph` to display the name, I added the `name` as part of the 'PdfPTable' and used `PdfPCell` and adjusted the colspan. Other than the name, this solution is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Perfect. Good to hear.